# Speaker on not working during calls Android 11

Tags: android, phone-call, speaker

The below code works fine on Android 10, 9, 8. But it doesn't work on Android 11.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (!mSpeakerOn) {
            //audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        } else {
            //audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
        }
```

I have ever tried with `setMode()` but it doesn't work as well. Just no action and no errors.
If someone has ever faced this issue and resolved it, please let me know how to deal with this problem. Thanks!

NOTE: I have tested with Samsung and LG phones.